# Keycloak Add OIDC identity provider does not support private_key_jwt authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect, idp

I'm running **Keycloak 4.8.3** server for identity brokering, and I need to add an external `OIDC` identity provider that does not support `client_id/client_secret` authentication.  This identity provider only supports `private_key_jwt` and `PKCE` authentication.

Unfortunately, **Keycloak** server only allows me to add `OIDC` identity providers with `client_id` and `client_secret` authentication.  Is there any way around this?  Maybe a plugin I can install for **Keycloak** server that allows me to add an identity provider with `private_key_jwt` authentication?

Comment: have a look at this thread: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2018-May/010883.html

Comment: @tryingToLearn thanks for the reply, but the thread you linked to is talking about a keycloak JavaScript client library.  What I need is to add an identity provider in the keycloak server, not the client.

Comment: Oh, ok. Will share more info if I find some. ( reply to comment regarding JS library link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have requested this feature and it has been identified as a legitimate feature request for which support should be added:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-9809